# How to use `onchange` for a drop-down in Vite?

Tags: typescript, vite

I ported over a project from raw JS to Vite/TypeScript, but having trouble getting the `onchange` of a few drop-down menus to work. Vite changes the names of functions/files, so I cannot do this:

`<select onchange="doAllSarf();" name="ayn" id="ayn" value="ayn">`

How is this typically done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right approach, but I ended up doing this, and it worked.

In my `main.ts`, I do this:

```
let faaelement = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("faa");
faaelement.onclick = doAllSarf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern development best practices avoid using strings that contain javascript as element properties, for *many* reasons. Here's a few:

- Javascript bundlers have a hard time understanding how the html uses the code and can't optimize your generated bundle.
- It's hard for your development environment to help you link code together, because it only sees a string and not executable code.
- It's too easy to make a syntax error or other mistake that isn't noticed until the button is clicked and it doesn't work.

Typescript especially, wants you to notice problems before anyone clicks that button. And in order for it to do that, you can't use strings that contain code as element properties.

---

Instead, bind the function to the element on the javascript side.

```js
function doAllSarf() {
    console.log('did all the sarf')
}

const select = document.getElementById('ayn') // as HTMLSelectElement
select.addEventListener('change', doAllSarf)
```

```html
<select name="ayn" id="ayn" value="ayn">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
```

Note that in TypeScript you'll need that commented out type assertion so that TypeScript knows that the element you just found is a `<select>` element.